# Grails: Organizing i18n bundles

Tags: grails, internationalization

I see under `grails-app/i18n` there are a ton of `messages*.properties` bundles. I would like to internationalize my app, but have 1 "bundle set" per page. By *bundle set* I mean, a set bundles/properties files that contain the same text but for different languages. For instance, if I want my site to support English, French and Spanish, then my "About" page might have a bundle set of 3 bundles:

- `about.properties` (English)
- `about_fr.properties` (French)
- `about_es.properties` (Spanish)

If my app consists of 100 pages, and I have 3 properties files per page, that's 300 properties files I'll eventually have under `grails-app/i18n`! Thats a can o' worms!

I'm wondering if I can added subfolders under `grails-app/i18n` and organize it in a decentralized fashion:

```
myapp/
    grails-app/
        i18n/
            about/
                about.properties
                about_fr.properties
                about_es.properties
            contact/
                contact.properties
                contact_fr.properties
                contact_es.properties
            fizzbuzz/
                fizzbuzz.properties
                fizzbuzz_fr.properties
                fizzbuzz_es.properties
            ... etc.
```

This would make for much nicer/cleaner/more organized code. If this is possible:

- Do I just create folders/packages under `grails-app/`i18n, or is there a Grails CLI command I can use (e.g., `grails create-i18n-bundle about`)?
- How do I then refer to my nested bundles from inside a GSP? For instance, in my `about.gsp`, would I just use: `<g:message code="about/foo.bar" />`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails takes all bundles that are under the grails-app/i18n folder. So you can create a folder for each of your groups.

To refer to them is just as simple as if it was in the messages.properties. 
I mean, if you have:

> grails-app/i18n/messages.properties

```
foo.bar = foo bar
```

> grails-app/i18n/about/about.properties

```
bar.foo = bar foo
```

You can do in your gsp:

```
<g:message code="foo.bar"/>
<g:message code="bar.foo"/>
```

Here you have a brief documentation: https://grails.org/wiki/Internationalization